# Android - app always shows "Hello World" after splash activity

Tags: android, layout

I'm new with Android.

I have an splash activity with a simple logo image and running this code on the `.java` class:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    private int SPLASH_TIEMPO = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_in_fade, R.anim.anim_out_fade);               
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIEMPO);

    }

}
```

Then, In my Login.class i don't have any code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }

}
```

In my login layout I made some designs. But when I run the application on my phone, It always shows the Hello world! text example:

[image]

What do you thing could be wrong?

**Edit:** In a debug mode, I see that the code to show the Login Activity is executing.

[image]

Comment: Surely, your `R.layout.login` is changed? And it doesn't contain just Text "Hello World".. right?

Comment: If you mean the `login.xml` file (in the layout folder), yes.

Comment: That's strange. Did you debug? That if code `startActivity(intent);` is being executed or not.

Comment: It is. I'll edit the question with SS.

Comment: Have you cleaned the project or restarted your IDE?

Comment: Damn it. It was my fault. I was setting a color with an empty value, so for any reason the activity just show an old text. Thanks for the help guys.